# Set lower limit when using matplotlib.axis('equal')

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot data with matplotlib where equal x and y increments have the same length. This works fine with

```
 ax1.axis('equal')
```

where ax1 is a     subfigure()

However setting the lower limits like this:

```
ax1.set_xlim(left=lowerlimit)
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=lowerlimit)
```

doesn't work. I also tried something like this which didn't work either:

```
ax1.axis('equal', xmin=lowerlimit,ymin=lowerlimit)
```

Can anyone help me?

Edit:
Here a minimal example to show the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y = [0,-1,-3,-2,-1,-2]
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax1.set_xlim(0,6)
ax1.set_ylim(0,-6)
ax1.axis('equal')
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=0)
plt.show()
```

Even though I explicitly set the lower limit of the y-axis to 0 after calling `ax1.set_ylim(bottom=0)` the lower limit of the plot is -1.

Comment: did you remember to call draw?

Comment: and can you put together a minimal example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I just added a minimal example.

Comment: I found out that one problem is that the new axis limits are set during saving the file with the pgf-backend. Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: that should not be happening....

Comment: But it does. If I check the limits right before saving the image by `print ax1.axis()` the lower limits for both axis are 0. If I do the same after saving the image by `plt.safefig("test.pdf")` at least one of the lower limits is negative.

Answer (score 1):

In your MWE, change:

```
ax1.axis('equal')
```

with:

```
ax1.set_aspect('equal',adjustable='box')
```

[image]